# How to iterate through range based for loop with variable end point

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I'm trying to use a range based for loop to iterate from the beginning of a vector to a variable index x as shown.

```
void algorithm(vector<int> arr, int n)
{
int count=0;
for (int i:arr[n])
count++;
}
```

I understand the above function is rather useless but I'm trying to conceptually understand if there is a way to do so. `arr[n]` gives me an error as does `arr.begin()+n`

Comment: Since the vector (presumably `arr`) is passed by value and changes to it won't be visible to the calluer, simply resize based on `n`, and then use a range-based loop `for (int i: arr)...`   as usual.     Otherwise, it is not possible to use a range-based for as you wish.

Comment: @Blaze my problem is that doing so will iterate through all of vector arr, my goal is to only iterate up to index n

Comment: @Risen Why not just  `for (int i=0; i<n; i++) std::cout << arr[i] << "\n";` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increment a counter and `break` the loop when the desired count is reached.

Something like:

```
void func(const std::vector<int> & v, std::size_t n)
{
    std::size_t count(0);

    for(int e : v)
    {
        if(count < n)
        {
            std::cout << e << " "; // Do what you want with e.
            ++count;
        }
        else
            break; // Exit the loop
    }
}
```

---

But **I would not recommend** doing it. Range-based for loops are meant to iterate over the whole container.
The above solution is thus a less readable way of simply doing:

```
void func(const std::vector<int> & v, std::size_t n)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; (i < v.size()) && (i < n); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << " "; // Do what you want with v[i].
    }
}
```

Or also:

```
void func(const std::vector<int> & v, std::size_t n)
{
    std::size_t count(0);
    for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = v.cbegin(); (cit != v.cend()) && (count < n); ++cit, ++count)
    {
        std::cout << *cit << " "; // Do what you want with *cit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Range-based for loop is pure sugar - it can only iterate over the entire range.

If you need to play with the iterators you have to fall back on a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documetion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) 
the for range loop is translate to :

```
{

    auto && __range = range_expression ;
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {

        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement

    }

}
```

so you can't set an ending point like you trying because its it a iterator to a place and its not arr.end().
but if you know the ending index you can try doing this:

```
vector<int> new_vec(arr.begin(), arr,(begin()+index));
for(auto& e:new_vec)
{
//some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the previous answers:

While at present this is not possible, C++20 will ship with much more support for ranges. I found [this article](https://ezoeryou.github.io/blog/article/2019-01-10-range-view.html) helpful in understanding some of the proposed features. As far as I understand you will be able to write

```
void algorithm(vector<int> arr, int n){
   int count=0;
   for (int i: arr | take(n))
      count++;
}
```

There is [no implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2020) of this proposal yet, so I am not aware of a way to test my code.